# Error: uninitialized local variable 'x' used

Tags: c

Buenas tardes o días a todos, quiero pedirles ayuda con este pequeño error que tengo, pido ayuda por que ya eh intentado varias cosas y me sigue saliendo este error, casi no tengo experiencia utilizando funciones en c, pero aquí les dejo mi código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int isdigit()
{
    int x, y;
    printf("inserte dos numeros\n");
    scanf_s("%d""%d",&x,&y);
    return x;
    return y;
}
int main()
{
    int x,y,z;
    isdigit();
    printf("%d\n", x);
    z = x + y;
    printf("%d\n",z);
}
```

el error me aparece tanto a la variable x como a y, intente colocando int x=0,y=0,z; pero no funciono, corría el programa pero a la hora de imprimir x y z me dan 0, sin importar los valores que insertara con scanf_s.

Comment: solucionado. muchas gracias, me informare mas sobre los punteros, y tampoco sabia que eran necesarios para poder retornar mas de un dato desde una función.

Comment: Podrías marcar la respuesta que más se acerca a tu respuesta como válida así la comunidad sabe la solución más cercana a tu problema. Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

Tenes varios errores de concepto. Te voy a poner el código que deberías utilizar y después te lo explico paso a paso:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo(int *x, int *y)
{
    printf("inserte dos numeros\n");
    scanf("%d""%d",x,y);
}
int main()
{
    int x,y,z;
    foo(&x, &y);
    z = x + y;
    printf("%d\n",z);
    return 0;
}
```

En primer lugar no deberías usar el nombre `isdigit` para tu función ya que es una función reservada de la librería [ctype](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isdigit.htm). Yo te cambie el nombre a `foo` pero dale el nombre que a vos te convenga.

Segundo, las funciones de `C` sólo pueden tener un valor de retorno, vos estas retornando 2, lo cual es incorrecto. De todas maneras también tenes un error de concepto, aunque hubieras retornado sólo un valor, nunca asignaste la función en tu programa principal, por ejemplo `x = foo()`.

Para retornar más de un valor en una función tenes que hacer pasajes por referencia (por defecto en `C` los parámetros se pasan por valor). Para hacer esto tenes que usar punteros, es decir, pasar la dirección de memoria del dato que querés modificar. De todas manera ya entraríamos en una explicación muy extensa sobre punteros.

Si no querés meterte con punteros, podes hacer la suma en la función y retornarla al programa principal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int foo()
{
    int x, y;
    printf("inserte dos numeros\n");
    scanf("%d""%d", &x, &y);
    return (x + y);

}
int main()
{
    int z;
    z = foo();
    printf("%d\n",z);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si analizamos esta función:

```
int isdigit()
{
    int x, y;
    printf("inserte dos numeros\n");
    scanf_s("%d""%d",&x,&y);
    return x;
    return y;
}
```

Vemos que tiene los siguientes errores:

- Nombre incorrecto. La función no comprueba que la entrada del usuario sean números... de hecho si en vez de números introduces letras el programa no va a mostrar ningún mensaje de error ni va a obrar en consecuencia. Que el nombre se solape con el de la librería `ctype.h` solo podría ser problemático si cargas esta librería en tu aplicación... aunque no estaría de más prevenir y evitar solapamientos... por si acaso
- Dos `return`. La triste realidad es que el programa abandonará la función en el primer `return`, por lo que el segundo jamás se ejecutará. Además la propia función indica que devuelve un único entero... no dice nada acerca de retornar dos valores. Para retornar un valor compuesto tendrías que hacerlo con un único `return`... y no es el caso.
- Equivocas el ámbito de las variables. Estás asumiendo que las variables `x` e `y` de esta función van a modificar el valor de las variables propias de `main`... y no es así. Estas variables son locales y su vida terminará cuando el programa abandone la función. Si quieres que el valor de estas variables perdure vía `return` tendrás que capturar el valor:

  ```
      int x = isdigit();
  ```

Posibles soluciones:

**Lectura simple**

Tienes una función que retorna un entero. Para leer dos valores tendrás que llamar a la función dos veces:

```
int readInt()
{
  int x;
  while( !scanf("%d",&x) )
  {
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); // limpieza del buffer de entrada
    printf("ERROR: No era un numero. Intentalo de nuevo: ");
  }

  return x;
}

int main()
{
  puts("Introduzca dos números: ");
  int x = readInt();
  int y = readInt();

  int z = x + y;
  printf("%d\n",z);
}
```

Ejemplo en [ideone](https://ideone.com/UZT8tW)

**Lectura doble con punteros**

En este caso la función lee los dos números y los devuelve. Para devolver los valores usa punteros recibidos como argumentos

```
void readInts(int* a, int* b)
{
  int x;
  while( scanf("%d %d",a,b) != 2 )
  {
    char c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); // limpieza del buffer de entrada
    printf("ERROR: Uno de los valores no era un número. Intentalo de nuevo: ");
  }

  return x;
}

int main()
{
  puts("Introduzca dos números: ");
  int x, y;
  readInts(&x,&y);

  int z = x + y;
  printf("Resultado: %d\n",z);
}
```

Ejemplo en [ideone](https://ideone.com/czjlGK)

**Lectura compuesta con retorno**

Como te he comentado, en C los valores devueltos se han de empaquetar en un único `return`. Esto no quiere decir que solamente se pueda devolver un entero... también se pueden devolver estructuras con toda la información que necesitamos:

```
typedef struct
{
  int x;
  int y;
} TwoInts;

TwoInts readInts()
{
  TwoInts toReturn;
  while( scanf("%d %d",&toReturn.x,&toReturn.y) != 2 )
  {
    char c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); // limpieza del buffer de entrada
    printf("ERROR: Uno de los valores no era un número. Intentalo de nuevo: ");
  }

  return toReturn;;
}

int main()
{
  puts("Introduzca dos números: ");
  TwoInts twoInts = readInts();

  int z = twoInts.x + twoInts.y;
  printf("Resultado: %d\n",z);
}
```

Ejemplo en [ideone](https://ideone.com/unweA0)